# Java Conditional Statement Exercises: Input numbers from keyboard and find their sum and use input "EXIT "to break the loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, input

I'm trying to create a loop by entering the number to be added and then blocking the loop with a "exit" input from the user..but it's not working properly.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class main {

  public static void main(String[] args)

  {       
      int i,n=0,s=0;
      double avg;
      {
   
       System.out.println("Input the numbers : ");  
     
   }
       for (i=0;i<100;i++)
       {
           String input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine ();
           if(input.equals("exit")){
               break;
           }
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           n = in.nextInt();
           s +=n;

   }
   System.out.println("The sum of numbers is : " +s);

  }
  }
```

Comment: This is wat I get out: Input the numbers :
20
19
293
1029
391
exit
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at main.main(main.java:22)

Comment: Put the above into the question **and format it properly** ... so that we can understand what it is saying. Use the ["edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62724674/edit) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. One (minor) is that you are creating two scanners. Another (medium) is that your loop is set up to only go up to 100 - this is a magic number, and there's no reason to put in this artificial constraint. But your biggest problem is that you are ignoring the first entry in the loop if it is a number and not 'exit'

```
  {       
      int i,n=0,s=0;
      double avg;
      boolean adding = true;
      System.out.println("Input the numbers : ");  
     Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
     while(adding)
       {
           String input = sc.nextLine ();
           if(input.equals("exit")){ // should proably be "EXIT" or equalsIgnoreCase
               adding = false;
           } else {
             try {
               int val = Integer.parseInt(input);
               s += val;
             } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
               System.err.println ("expecting EXIT or an integer");
             }
           }

   }
   System.out.println("The sum of numbers is : " +s);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line your console does not have any next line or entry to read.

String input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine ();